# Vue 3 Table using Slots

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

i have a very specific question about Vue3 and slots and i've created the following components for a re-usable table.

**FSTable.vue**

```js
<template>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <slot renderAs="header"></slot>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(row, index) of rows" :key="index">
        <slot renderAs="cell" :row="row"></slot>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  const rows = [{
    name: "Row 1",
    col2: "XX",
    col3: "YY"
  },
  {
    name: "Row 2",
    col2: "XX",
    col3: "YY"
  },
  {
    name: "Row 3",
    col2: "XX",
    col3: "YY"
  }];
</script>
```

**FSTableColumn.vue**

```js
<template>
  <th v-if="props.renderAs === 'header'" class="p-2">
    <slot name="header" :header="props.header">
      {{ props.header }}
    </slot>
  </th>
  <td v-else-if="props.renderAs === 'cell'" class="p-2">
    <slot :value="props.property ? row[props.property] : row">
      {{ props.property ? row[props.property] : "" }}
    </slot>
  </td>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  const props = defineProps<{
    renderAs?: string;
    header?: string;
    property?: string;
    row?: any;
  }>();
</script>
```

As you can see, the FSTableColumn is rendered either as a header or as a cell.

**Usage**

```js
<FSTable v-slot="slotProps">
  <FSTableColumn v-bind="slotProps" header="Column 1" property="name" v-slot="cellProps">
    <!-- This column renders a custom cell -->
    CustomCell: {{ cellProps.value }}
  </FSTableColumn>
  <FSTableColumn v-bind="slotProps" header="Column 2" property="col2">
    <!-- This column renders the default cell -->
  </FSTableColumn>
  <FSTableColumn v-bind="slotProps" header="Column 3" property="col3">
    <!-- This column renders a custom header -->
    <template #header="headerProps">
      CustomHeader: {{ headerProps.header }}
    </template>
  </FSTableColumn>
</FSTable>
```

**Question**
As you can see, i need to pass down the *slotProps* from *FSTable* to *FSTableColumn*.
Is it possible to get rid of this and pass them implicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a functional component in the table to add slot props to the columns automatically:

[VUE SFC PLAYGROUND](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```
<script setup>
  const rows = [{
    name: "Row 1",
    col2: "XX",
    col3: "YY"
  },
  {
    name: "Row 2",
    col2: "XX",
    col3: "YY"
  },
  {
    name: "Row 3",
    col2: "XX",
    col3: "YY"
  }];

import { useSlots } from 'vue';

const slots = useSlots();

const renderCols = props => {

  const cols = slots.default();
  cols.forEach(vnode => Object.assign(vnode.props ??= {}, props));
  return cols;

};
</script>


<template>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <render-cols renderAs="header"/>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(row, index) of rows" :key="index">
        <render-cols renderAs="cell" :row="row"/>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

The usage:

```
<script setup>
import FSTable from './FSTable.vue';
import FSTableColumn from './FSTableColumn.vue';
import { ref } from 'vue'

const msg = ref('Hello World!')
</script>

<template>
<FSTable>
  <FSTableColumn header="Column 1" property="name" v-slot="cellProps">
    <!-- This column renders a custom cell -->
    CustomCell: {{ cellProps.value }}
  </FSTableColumn>
  <FSTableColumn header="Column 2" property="col2">
    <!-- This column renders the default cell -->
  </FSTableColumn>
  <FSTableColumn header="Column 3" property="col3">
    <!-- This column renders a custom header -->
    <template #header="headerProps">
      CustomHeader: {{ headerProps.header }}
    </template>
  </FSTableColumn>
</FSTable>
</template>
```